# How to disable line breaks in anchor elements in IE11

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the *DOM* elements rendered from a directive which goes like this :

```
<div>
 <p>
 text 1 
  <a>text</a>
 text 2
 <p>
</div>
```

In all browsers it is viewed as expected like this :

```
text 1 text text 2
```

Except in *IE* `11` which is rendered like below :

```
text 1
text
text 2
```

I've tried to add a `display:inline` rule to the anchor element and it didn't work, however when I switched the `<p>` element with a `<div>` it was working as expected, but in reality I can't change the content of the directive, so what I can I do to fix this.

Comment: i dont see any issue with this its working fine for me. can you please share your IE version details

Comment: Same here. I tested your code in IE11 and everything works fine. Maybe you have some additional styles that makes your anchor display as block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because inline or inline-block trigger hashlayouts,

have you tried to use zoom:1; ?

Your code would look a bit like this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 70px; display:inline; zoom:1;">
 <p>
 text 1 
  <a>text</a>
 text 2
 </p>
</div>
```

Maybe apply the style to the `<p>` since that might work

I hope this helped

Comment: `display: inline-flex;` might work aswell have you tried that yet?